# VBScript and VBA - namespace issues

Tags: vba, vbscript, namespaces

I want to automate some steps using VBA, and I also want to be able to execute everything from the command line. In my example I'm using Corel Draw, but I think that my question is independent from Corel Draw - its more a question about namespaces.

So I wrote the following small script (called `foo.vbs`):

```
dim drawApp
Set drawApp = CreateObject( "CorelDraw.Application.14" )
drawApp.OpenDocument( "C:\foo\bar.cdr" )

Dim exportFilter
set exportFilter = drawApp.ActiveDocument.ExportBitmap("bar.png", cdrPNG, cdrAllPages, cdrRGBColorImage, 10206, 8578, 300, 300, cdrNormalAntiAliasing, False, False, True, False, cdrCompressionNone)
```

Then, I run it from the command line:

`cscript.exe foo.vbs`

I get the error that `cdrPNG` is not defined. Of course - I did not include any Corel Draw specific stuff into the VBScript. But how do I incluce VBA stuff that is specific for one application? (This might also enable me to write `dim drawApp as CorelDRAW.Application` or something like that).

I'm very new to VBA and VBScripts and I have not been able to find good tutorials or reference resources (the Microsoft site is not very helpful). Any pointers welcome.

**EDIT:**

I copied the `ExportBitmap`-part from the code that was generated when I recored a macro in Corel Draw. Studying code from recored macros seems a nice way to get to know the VBA capabilities of the software. Is there a better way?

Comment: in your script I do not see you define cdrPNG.  Is this a enumeration from Coral Draw?

Comment: Yes, it is. I copied the code that was generated when I recored a macro in Corel DRAW...

Comment: I fear that you have not choice than defining them yourself by Const cdrPNG= "My Constant Value" or Const cdrPNG = MyNumericValue on the head of your VBScript.

Comment: you need to reference CoralDraw in order for it to know the association.   drawApp.Application.crdPNG     <-- not sure if that is the correct path to the enum as I do not have CoralDraw ont his machine.   Take a look at this doc for some info that may help. http://apps.corel.com/partners_developers/csp/resources/dvba_pg.pdf

Comment: Is this the only way? Is there no way to access the enums that I could access when I write 'embedded VBA'?

Comment: Yes, that's the only way.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers do you accept wsf files as a way? Because it's a way to achieve enum constants from type library.

Comment: @Kul-Tigin WSF is not VBScript.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Yes I'm aware it's not VBScript, already mentioned as "script package". It's just a way like "adding constants manually". "adding constants manually" is not VBScript also, is not it? I asked because I care about your opinion. And I got the answer. I think :/

Comment: @Kul-Tigin My comment was only about VBScript. There are ways in other languages/environments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you considered to use a `.wsf` script package instead `.vbs` script file, everything would be easier for you. Adding type libraries supported in [WSF files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15x4407c%28v=vs.84%29.aspx).

```xml
<package>
    <job id="Main">
        <!-- 
        add type library reference specifying progid and version
        then all enum constants will be ready to use
        -->
        <reference object="CorelDraw.Application" version="14.0" />
        <script language="VBScript">
            Option Explicit

            Dim drawApp
            Set drawApp = CreateObject("CorelDraw.Application.14")
                drawApp.OpenDocument("C:\foo\bar.cdr")

            Dim exportFilter
            Set exportFilter = drawApp.ActiveDocument.ExportBitmap( _ 
            "C:\foo\bar.png", cdrPNG, cdrAllPages, cdrRGBColorImage, 10206, 8578, 300, 300, _ 
            cdrNormalAntiAliasing, False, False, True, False, cdrCompressionNone, Nothing, Nothing)
                exportFilter.Finish
                drawApp.Quit
        </script>
    </job>
</package>
```