# Is there a way to determine the value of a type library constant such as dbFailOnError in VBScript?

Tags: vbscript, typelib

When writing a VBScript, I often need the values of constants that are defined in type libraries such as `dbFailOnError` whose value is defined in a type library. Usually, I find the value of such a constant when I open the according Office application (in this case: Access) and `msgBox dbFailOnError`. This works, but is somewhat clumsy.

I think, it should somehow be possible to write something like

```
dim dbFailOnError
dbFailOnError = typeLibConstants("ACEDAO.DLL", "dbFailOnError")
```

Is this the case?

Comment: it's not supported in `.vbs` files. all you can find like `typeLibConstants()` would be 3rd party. instead have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/20011093/893670

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBScript and VBA - namespace issues](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20005087/vbscript-and-vba-namespace-issues)