# How do I reference wbemErrAccessDenied in a vbscript

Tags: vbscript

I found a snippet of code that allows me to connect to an exchange server to run some tests. The code I'm trying to use reads in part:

```
  '----- Get a connection to the Exchange Server -----

  Set objSWbemLocator  = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator")
  Set objSWbemServices = objSWbemLocator.ConnectServer(sServer, "Root\CIMv2", gsUser, gsPassword)

  If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    If Err.Number = objSWbemLocator.wbemErrAccessDenied Then
```

The finished script works fine. However, if there is an error in the connection attempt, the error handling doesn't work and I get the following error:

> Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this
> property or method: 'objSWbemLocator.wbemErrAccessDenied'

The problem occurs in the last line where I try to determine the exact error. I use vbscripts very infrequently and don't know the proper way to reference this error. I find the wbemErrAccessDenied error defined in Microsoft literature but I can't find anything about how to use it.

Comment: It's a constant value from the `WbemErrorEnum` enumeration, see the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wbemdisp/ne-wbemdisp-wbemerrorenum).

Comment: Define the constant - `Const wbemErrAccessDenied = &H80041003` then you can test for it in your code.

Comment: I was hoping for a way to use the enumeration. It seems not. Thanks.

Comment: VBScript does not support type libraries, so any constants have to be brought in manually. But [WSF does](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20011093/692942) if that is an option and you don't want to have to define them yourself.